# closing a window

Tags: c#

If I am closing a window I want to know by which way the window gets closed (i.e)
by a mouse click in the close icon  or alt+f4. Is there any event for getting this info?

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe there are any events specifically to give you this information, no. The `FormClosingEvent` provides a `FormClosingEventArgs` with a `CloseReason`, but the reason doesn't distinguish between using a mouse or the keyboard. It only distinguishes between a "user close" event and things like "the form owner closed" or "the application was shut down from task manager."

Answer (score 2):

Whether or not you can trap specific WM_...-messages to distinguish between them, **don't do it**! One of the fundamental pricniples of usability is no suprises: live up to the user's expectations. Do what every other application does, especially when it comes to the absolute basics.

Answer (score 1):

No matter which toolkit you're using there are always events for clicks on the close button, keyboard events for Alt+F4, menu click events for menus etc. All you have to do is enumerate the possible ways to quit your application, change the event handlers to set a variable to their corresponding value, and check that variable in your application close procedures.